# Table-like grid with borders without using table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a grid that would allow the "rows" of content inside to have dynamic height but at the same time keep borders around each "cell". I can't think of a way to do this that wouldn't involve nasty hacks and need some help.

The following schematic explains what I'm after and what I've tried so far:

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/111mpsn/5]

Ideally:

- No table because of rendering reasons, although it would certainly work
- Should be IE6/IE7-friendly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables would be the ideal solution, but as you mentioned aren't valid for you in this instance.

The use of `display: table-cell;` also will not work for you as IE6/7 do not support it.

Your best bet would be to follow something like the method outlined [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks). In essence, you will need to create a wrapping row div for each cell with a right border (Or any other styles you want) and then relatively position them to the left an amount equal to the width of the cell. Not a pretty solution, but it is a hard problem to solve otherwise.

Alternatively, you could make [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) where the borders (and backgrounds if you want) of the table cells are really just part of a background image applied to the row and repeated vertically. This would be much simpler HTML and CSS wise, but requires making an image out of the styles, which could be a huge pain whenever you want to change something.

Comment: Thanks... I think the link you provided is what I'm after. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of messy, but it works in IE9, FF, Chrome, & Safari (the last three also on the Mac versions).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .containerDiv {
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            width: 903px;
        }
        .rowDiv {
            border-top: 1px solid black;
        }
        .cellDiv {
            border-right: 1px solid black;
            display: table-cell;
            width:300px;
            padding: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="containerDiv">
        <div class="rowDiv">
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text.</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowDiv">
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text.</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text.</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowDiv">
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text.</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowDiv">
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text.</div>
            <div class="cellDiv">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

The trick is to set the `.cellDiv` divs to `display: table-cell`. You also have to give them a width. The main container width is 3 pixels wider than the sum of the interior widths, to account for the border widths. Note how the borders are manipulated so that only a single line is apparent.